# Remove image from cache in ionic app

Tags: caching, ionic-framework

I'm creating an Android app with Ionic and in controller.js file, I'm showing image from URL. It shows very well, but if I change the image on server, in app old image is displayed. How can I make sure that updated, new image is shown in app? Following is the code -

```
document.getElementById("news1Img").src="http://someserver.com/folder/news1Img.png";
```

How can I clear cache in that view? (Pls note - I've already added cache-view="false")
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js

Comment: You can send listener from your server to ionic where the image url had been changed.

Comment: try to use ng-src instead of src.

Comment: @raj - not sure how to use ng-src in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one, I hope it will work

```
document.getElementById("news1Img").src="http://someserver.com/folder/news1Img.png?time=12322";
```

Comment: tried this, but still app shows old image only, even after app is restarted on device.

Comment: You need to change the url dynamically. then you can get new updated image. if u upload your controller code, i can fix this issue.

Comment: .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$state,$http) {
    
    /* Load the News and Updates from server */    
      $http.get("http://smashingwheels.com/ridewise/news.json", { params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" } })
            .success(function(data) {                
                //News 1 
                document.getElementById("news1Data").innerHTML = data.news1;
                document.getElementById("news1Img").src="http://smashingwheels.com/ridewise/news1Img.png";
            })
            .error(function(data) {            
})

Comment: In your controller, you are giving hard codded image path directly. It should be from server right? from where you get path of images of all?

Comment: I've only hard coded image path from server. Idea is to load news text from JSON file (which works fine) and load related image from server with that url. If news changes, I'll update JSON file and will replace image on server with that url and by keeping same file name.

Comment: it looks like problem has been resolved by adding "?time" in URL. Thanks a ton for help! Could you please add some notes on adding time in URL and how it worked? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable cache this way from app.js

```
.config(function ($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
})
```

Comment: Sharad - tried this, but still old image is displayed.